# create a javascript object by string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, devexpress

I want to access a usercontrol by a predifened name, like the DevExpress components can. Something like this:

```
"<dx:MyUserControl runat="server" ID="My" ClientInstanceName="MyClient"></>"
```

In my main page I would like to access a client method of my usercontrol.
Something like:

```
MyClient.DoSomething();
```

In my usercontrol page there would be an object that implements this method:

```
function myClass{
    DoSomething : function(){ var a = 2 + 2;}
}
```

So, normally I would declare the object like :
    var MyClient = new myClass();

But now MyClient is dynamic, the `ClientInstanceName` could be whatever...

So how could I do this?

Maybe JSON or eval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit dual meaning, so let me post answer of both the meanings that I found.

You have a variable named `MyClient` and a class named `myClass`.

Now, even if we assume both the names here are dynamic, and you get and store both the names in variables `A` and `B`, such that

if `B` equals `"foobar"` , then you are sure that there is a class on the page like

```
function foobar() { ... }
```

and if `A` equals `"myFoobar"`, you know that you have to actually do something like

```
var myFoobar = new foobar();
```

Now, since both the variable and the class are globally scoped, you can easily do

```
window[A] = new window[B]();
```

and that's it!

Comment: So does it mean, that in my usercontrol page I could also declare something like: var myObject = new myClass(); window['<%# clientInstanceName %>'] = myObject;

Comment: Not sure what the JS of your page is like, but if the class is a global class (not inside any function), then you can do this.

Comment: <%# clientInstanceName %> does not seem like valid JS, is someone preprocessing it ? If yes, and that someone is simply replacing `<%# clientInstanceName %>` with a string, then yes.

Comment: Yes it is a server property (string)that i set in the declaration of my usercontrol.